# Infinity Loop does not end when program is closed

Tags: c++, qt, subclass, infinite-loop, qthread

I have an infinity loop whithin the run-method of my `QThread subclass`. This thread should exist till the application is closed. The Code looks something like this.

loopThread.h:

```
class loopThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    loopThread();
    ~loopThread();
  

protected:
    void run() override;
    
signals:
    void resultReady();

};
```

The implementation of the subclass is as follows:

loopThread.cpp:

```
void loopThread::run()
{   while(!this->isInterruptionRequested()){
    std::cout << "loop active" << std::endl; //checking if it executes the loop or not
    }
}
```

the `run()-method` executes a infinity loop until `requesInterruption()` is called in the `mainWindow class`.

MainWindow.h:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);
        
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    loopThread *loopThread = nullptr;

public slots:
    void handleResult();
};
```

The Implementation for this class says

MainWindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    loopThread = new loopThread();
    connect(loopThread, &loopThread::noButtonClicked, this, &loopThread::NoButton);
    connect(loopThread, &loopThread::finished, loopThread, &loopThread::deleteLater);
    loopThread->start();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    loopThread->quit();
    loopThread->wait();

    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    loopThread->requestInterruption();
   
}
```

So I would suggest that when I close the application by clicking in the "X" in the window the loop should end and the program should stop. The problem is even after closing the window the Console gives me the message "loop active" so it the loop still goes on. Where's my mistake. Is there a way to let a loop end when the program is closed?
The solution with moving a `QObject` to a Thread produces the same problem.

Comment: We cannot answer this without seeing the definitions for `loopthread::quit`, `loopthread::wait`, `loopthread::requestInterruption`, and `loopthread::isInterruptionRequested`.  Also, find a way to test this other than having your code flood the console with text, because that may cause other problems.  E.g. print your message 2x/sec.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53: These are all functions of QThread...

Comment: @matthias-kawalek: Is closeEvent() really called? I would also add a requestInterruption() to the dtor

Comment: Based on your provided code i created a project and it works. 
As already stated by first comment your thread floods console with output.
If i start the application from console window thread output stops immediately after closing main window.
If i start the application from Qt Creator it takes a while until complete output has been dumped to "Application Output" window.
You might add a sleep of some microseconds after each console output to avoid flooding.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys!

I managed to solve this problem. AS said the infinite loop in the run()-method just send the message to the console. I have avoided this by just let the loop run without any task.
in my case i needed to check the serialcommunication so with the signal readyRead() i can now read this serial message. The loop is therfore executed until i stop the app. hopefulle that doesnt confuse too much. I will post my code when i have time.